# Is that possible to check subscription iap from another user unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

This question seem wierd. But it is like the title question said about. I need to check if the subscription from another user is still active or not.

Example :
I have admin app and client app.
Admin app user will do a subscription iap so a client app user can enjoy the feature.

If admin app user stop the subscription then client app user will no longer see the feature in the client app.

Is that possible for a client user app to check if the admin app user is still subscribe to the developer or not ?

I am developing this using a unity engine c#.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is very simple.

You have to change your perspective. You should provide the subscription facility to the admin app only. You don't need to provide it to the client as they are not going to purchase the feature.

Host a backend that manages the subscription details and provides methods for the client app user to check whether the admin app user has an active subscription.

**Subscription flow:**
[image]

**Client feature request flow:** The client doesn't have to check the subscription details directly from the Google API, **the server has to maintain the subscription details though.**

[image]

Comment: The problem is in client how to know if the admin did not subscribe anymore since the admin did not login to the app and cannot update the database to check if the subscription is still active or not.

Comment: The admin doesn't have to be logged in to check the status that's work of the web API.